# handling multiple plot objects at once

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a method with a loop that creates multiple boxplots given by a list input of a given data frame:

```
def create_boxplots(data_frame):
    x_axis_attr = [columnA, columnB, columnC]
    for index in range(len(x_axis_attr)):
         boxplot = sns.boxplot(x=data_frame[x_axis_attr[index]])
         plot_dict.update({"boxplot " + x_axis_attr[index]: boxplot})

    return plot_dict
```

The plot saving is handled by a different module, so the created plots get returned in a dict().

Turns out that the plots are not saved in different objects:

```
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x181640D0>, 
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x181640D0>, 
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x181640D0>]
```

Even if I am saving the figure with: `boxplot.get_figure()`:

```
[<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x18C37F30>, 
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x18C37F30>, 
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x18C37F30>]
```

Note: 
1. if execute `plt.show()` in the loop, all the boxplots are shown correctly

How can I make sure that all the plots get their own objects and **don't** share the memory?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A new figure is created e.g. via `plt.figure()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked for me if  plt.figure()  is called before any plotting.